# SharePoint Server return page cannot displayed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have SharePoint App, WFE and DB Servers. I have run SP Configuration wizard after that AppServer and DBServer  return page cannot be displayed if I open the Site.  But site is working fine if open in WFE server. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set AAM in your SharePoint 2013?

If you run SharePoint Configuration wizard, it will re-configure some settings.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Reboot the servers.
2. Check if the servers can communicate with each other.
3. Check if you have configured the firewall in servers.